# checking condition and displaying two different message using setCustomValidity

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check two conditions in the html form text field validation. In the below code it checks and shows whether the phone number entered is in the right format. If it is wrong, it displays a message 'Enter a valid mobile number' as I set in setCustomValidity. But it shows the same message when the field is blank. But I want to it to display a different message like 'Please fill this form' when theis field is blank. Is it possible to do it in with html itself as I have used html validation for all the other fields.

```
<input name="phno" type="text" size="50" maxlength="10"  pattern="[0-9]{10}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter a valid mobile number')"
    `oninput=`"setCustomValidity('')" required/></td>
```

Comment: What does your `setCustomValidity` function has

Comment: It checks the pattern if the phone number has 10 digits

Comment: in there add a extra condition if its empty display a different message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inline conditions of html pattern are in JavaScript so simply add this `if (this.value!='')`:

```
<input name="phno" type="text" size="50" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" oninvalid="if (this.value!=''){this.setCustomValidity('Enter a valid mobile number')}"  oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required/>
```